# Choosing Vite .env.development variables for firebase hosting deployment

Tags: deployment, environment-variables, vite, firebase-hosting

I have a file named .env.production and .env.development. I can build my app manually using the dev variables but once I call `firebase deploy --only functions` it rebuilds the my app using the production variables.
Is there a way to prevent firebase from rebuilding using the production variables?

I have tried

```
"hosting": {
    "predeploy": "vite build --mode development",
}
```

```
 "scripts": {
    "deploy:dev": "vite build --mode development && firebase deploy --only hosting"
  },
```

Thank You!!